# How do I break a Shadow Orb?

Tags: terraria

I'd like to summon a Goblin Army, and I know that I need 200 Health and a Shadow Orb. But how do I get a Shadow Orb without an op pickaxe? Also, I have a Crimson biome, not a Corruption so how do I get a Shadow Orb? In addition, do I need anything else to spawn a Goblin invasion other than 200 Health and a shadow orb?

Comment: I would argue that this, while having a similar title, is not a duplicate.

Comment: That edit makes no sense.  He's not asking how to break a Shadow Orb.  He just wants to know how to summon the Goblin Army.

Comment: @Frank Did you read the original question? It's exactly what he asked, except for the little mention of additional requirements right at the end. It's obvious that the main reason was to ask about how to break an orb, and if there's anything like it in a Crimson World. I do not talk about invasions at all in my answer and it was accepted, so I'd think that's a pretty good indication of what the question was asking.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Nope, I read the original question, and I think you're reading way too much into it.  He wants the goblin army, and is having trouble acquiring a shadow orb, or something.  He's not asking how to break one.

Comment: @Frank I'm afraid I'm just going to have to say you're wrong, then. Because that is exactly what he's asking.

Comment: you can destroy them with explosive ,y'know.

Comment: @Frank Shadow Orbs in Terraria are not collectible items. They are environmental fixtures that can only be interacted with through breaking them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking a Crimson Heart will have the same effect as breaking a Shadow Orb. As to how to reach it, you have 3 main ways.

- The most straightforward, but also the hardest, is to get a pickaxe that can mine Crimstone. Right now, your only choice is to fish a Reaver Shark from the ocean, but it's a pretty low chance.
- The second way is to remove Crimstone blocks through a different method; explosions from Bombs and Dynamite can destroy Crimstone, and you can craft Sticky Bombs with Gel and Bombs to carefully aim your explosions against walls. This requires a decent amount of explosives, though.
- The easiest and cheapest way is to purchase Purification Powder from the Dryad, which turns Crimstone into normal Stone Blocks, which are then easily mined away.

Comment: @tjd Actually, they can only mine Crimtane, not Crimstone.